# Switch executes default even with break in every case

Tags: java, switch-statement, break

So i'm trying to break out of the `switch` and `while` statements using the break in every case, yet even using the `break` statement my program keeps executing the default after the specific case code is executed, i'v tried for hours now yet i can't find a way arround it what should i do?

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Creates scanner for user input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Creates variables to define the size of the array and the value to make the operations
        int arraySize, arrayCalc;

        //Gets the size of the array
        System.out.println("Please enter the size of your array:");
        arraySize = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        //Repeats if array size is zero
        while (arraySize <= 0) {
            System.out.println("The size of your array is too small, please set a bigger value:");
            arraySize = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
        }

        //Gets the values of the array
        int[] array = new int[arraySize];
        System.out.println("Please enter the values for your array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please, put the char compatible with the operation you want to do:");

        //Loop in case operator is not valid
        boolean validOperator = false;
        while(!validOperator) {

            //Sets the operator
            String operation = input.nextLine();

            switch (operation) {

                case "+":

                    //Addition operation
                    System.out.println("Please enter what value you would like to add to your array:");
                    arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    while (arrayCalc < 0) {
                        System.out.println("The value you have entered is too small, please use a bigger number:");
                        arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    }

                    //Makes the operation
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                        array[i] = array[i] + arrayCalc;
                    }

                    break;

                case "-":

                    //Subtraction operation
                    System.out.println("Please enter what value you would like to subtract to your array:");
                    arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    while (arrayCalc < 0) {
                        System.out.println("The value you have entered is too small, please use a bigger number:");
                        arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    }

                    //Makes the operation
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                        array[i] = array[i] - arrayCalc;
                    }
                    break;

                case "*":

                    //Multiplication operation
                    System.out.println("Please enter what value you would like to multiply to your array:");
                    arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    while (arrayCalc < 0) {
                        System.out.println("The value you have entered is too small, please use a bigger number:");
                        arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    }

                    //Makes the operation
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                        array[i] = array[i] * arrayCalc;
                    }
                    break;

                case "/":

                    //Division operation
                    System.out.println("Please enter what value you would like to divide to your array:");
                    arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    while (arrayCalc < 0) {
                        System.out.println("The value you have entered is too small, please use a bigger number:");
                        arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    }

                    //Makes the operation
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                        array[i] = array[i] / arrayCalc;
                    }
                    break;

                default:

                    //Exception if input is not a proper operator
                    System.out.println("That's not a valid operator! try \"+\" \"-\" \"*\" or \"/\".");

            }
        }

        //Prints the operation
        System.out.print("Those are your numbers after the operation: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize- 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
            if (i == arraySize - 2) {
                System.out.println(array[i + 1] + ".");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the loop is iterating a second time, the whole `switch` is being executed again - seems like [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/85421) || Why **always** reading another `operation` ?

Comment: You never set validOperator to true so it is always going to loop.

Comment: I see, from your previous question: the first comment is missing the part about setting `validOperator  true`!

Comment: in more words: the code must set `validOperator = true;` if an operator is recognized (as valid), that is, inside/after each `case`, but not inside `default` - this will terminate the `while` loop before its next iteration. But be aware that next call to `Scanner.nextLine()` will probably return an empty string left over from previous call to `nextInt()` (unless more data was entered on same line as that integer)

Comment: @user85421 i made it get the input of another operator in case the one that was chosen was not a proper one, so it'll warn you that the input is not valid and be able to recieve another one afterwards

Comment: I understand that, but `nextInt()` does not *consume* the linefeed after reading the number; so if you call `nextLine()` it will read up to the linefeed (still on the same line as the `int`) and return an empty line -- that is the reason why you call `nextLine()` after reading `arraySize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put validOperator = true; before every break statement in case block.